# Node as Hash not Array in RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nodes, rabl

I have this RABL template:

```
object :@pollution => nil
attributes :id, :time
node :components do |p|
  p.components.map do |component|
    { component.name => { level: component.level, main: component.main } }
  end
end
```

It renders

```
{ "id":820,
  "time":"2017-05-12 20:00:00 UTC",
  "components": [ # I don't need this array
    { "component1": { "level": 3, "main": false } },
    { "component2": { "level": 5, "main": false } },
  ]
}
```

And I want this

```
{ "id":820,
  "time":"2017-05-12 20:00:00 UTC",
  "components": {
    "component1": { "level": 3, "main" :false },
    "component2": { "level": 5, "main" :false },
  }
}
```

So, instead of array of components, I need a hash, where keys will be components names and value — hash with components data (`level(Int)` and `main(Bool)`).

I tried to render `child :components`, but it also renders an array.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried using `p.components.inject({}) { |components, component| components[component.name] = { level: component.level, main: component.main }}` ?

Comment: I receive this in: `... "components": { "level": 3, "main" :false }` Only one element without name.

Comment: did you wrap it with `node :components do |p|` ?

Comment: Yes. Only one element.

Comment: Ahh!!! got it, I think I didn't get what you wrote. Sorry, I know what;s the error. Change the line to a block with `do`, and after the line that's currently in the block, put `components` so that it gets passed to the next iteration: `p.components.inject({}) { |components, component| components[component.name] = { level: component.level, main: component.main }; components}`. that's in one line, split it where the `;` is and use `do` instead of `{}` so that it's more readable.

Comment: Great! it works! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, you need to change these lines:

```
p.components.map do |component|
  { component.name => { level: component.level, main: component.main } }
end
```

which are returning an array, to something like:

```
p.components.inject({}) do |components, component|
  components[component.name] = { level: component.level, main: component.main }
  components
end
```

that will build a hash instead of an array.